# Why is the max chunk length 16383 in conversion of byte array to base64?

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64, chunked-encoding

I'm trying to understand the conversion of byte array to base64. In the below link line number 124

```
https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js/blob/master/index.js
```

Why is the max chunk length taken as 16383 and what is the use of taking the chunk length?